# User Dynamically Running Methods and Creating Objects

Tags: c#, .net, class, user-interface, methods

So there are two .NET class libraries with various classes and methods.

Right now there is a static set of operations. For example:

```
// Create and connect to device objects
classLibrary1.device objectDevice1 = new classLibrary1.device();
classLibrary2.device objectDevice2 = new classLibrary2.device();

// First Operation
objectDevice1.setSetting1(uiInput1.Text);
objectDevice1.doOperation1();

// Second Operation
// Create parameter object
classLibrary2.operationParam parameters = new classLibrary2.operationParam();
parameters.setParam1(uiInput2.Text);
parameters.setParam2(uiInput3.Text);
// Do operation with parameters
objectDevice2.doOperation1(parameters);
```

So the user is able to input certain parameters in the interface, but the operation is static.

The goal is to have the user build a custom event with operations such as:

```
Set property on device1
Call method 'doOperation1' on device1
Create operationParameter 'parameter'
Set 'setParam1' on 'parameter' as '100'
Set 'setParam2' on 'parameter' as '200'
Call method 'doOperation1' on device2 with 'parameter'
Create operationParameter 'parameter2'
Set 'setParam1' on 'parameter2' as '500'
Set 'setParam2' on 'parameter2' as '600'
Call method 'doOperation1' on device2 with 'parameter2'
Call method 'doOperation2' on device1
```

The possible options for the user would be:

1. Run through a wizard which the user would select the type of event, set the parameters, and it would build the event with the proper operations.
2. Build the event manually adding each operation.
3. First build with the wizard and then edit the event to add in operations
   inbetween the generated ones.

The interface would include a dropdown to access the methods/properties, with input fields for the required parameters when the user selects from the dropdown.  I don't know if it would be possible to build or implement a interpreter as well that would allow the user to 'write' such an event.

There are about 40 different methods, each with various properties or separate parameter objects required.

What would be the best way to structure this code?  I've been able to get reflection to set properties by creating an 'event' object that contains a List of 'operation' objects.  The data is pulled from a SQLite DB as the method/property name and parameters.  Since it's in the DB as a string, I have not tested Convert.ChangeType with multiple parameters so methods are not working as of now.

```
        MethodInfo method = this.objectType.GetMethod(this.methodName);
        if (method != null)
        {
            object result = null;
            ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = method.GetParameters();
            if (paramInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                result = method.Invoke(instance, null);
            }
            else
            {
                result = method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            PropertyInfo pi = objectType.GetProperty(methodName);
            if (pi != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(parameters[0],pi.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
```

I'm more concerned about dynamically creating the parameter object(s), and being able to reference them in the methods. i.e:

```
// Create parameter object
classLibrary2.operationParam parameters = new classLibrary2.operationParam();
parameters.setParam1(uiInput2.Text);
parameters.setParam2(uiInput3.Text);
// Do operation with parameters
objectDevice2.doOperation1(parameters);
```

Is there a way to leverage the exposed methods of the .NET library, or is it necessary to write a wrapper for all the methods.

I have not been able to find anything similar to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can generate code at runtime using Expressions or Reflection.Emit.  It sounds like you should be able to generate an expression tree from the wizard result and either modify the tree or rebuild it if the user changes the settings. Have a look at [this book chapter](http://www.manning.com/hazzard/metadotnet_sample_ch06.pdf) for an overview of using the Expression API.